# How to build String List with Toggle Buttons

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a command list for ProcessBuilder running a program  depending on what is selected on GUI.

I have 10 buttons and i need each button to return and add a String to List
when toggled and remove it while not toggled.

I was trying to add value to the list when .isSelected and remove it when disabled.
But i think this is not a good approach.

Does anyone have any ideas ?

EDIT: Is adding all buttons to ToggleGroup and use Switch is a valid solution ?

Comment: If you add all the buttons to a toggle group, only one button can be selected at a time, which is probably not what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys I went for something like this:

```
public ToggleButton getBuildBtn() {

        final ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton("Build");

        button.setStyle("-fx-font: 15 verdana; -fx-base: " + buttonsColor + ";");
        button.setOnAction(event -> selectedhandler(button, "build"));
        return button;
}

private void selectedhandler(final ToggleButton button, String command) {
    if (button.isSelected()) {
        button.setStyle("-fx-base: #00ff0f;");
        commands.add(command);
    } else {
        button.setStyle("-fx-base: " + buttonsColor + ";");
        commands.remove(command);
    }
}
```

I will think about enumSet while refactoring. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A simple implementation is:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private final List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox commandToggles = new VBox();
        commandToggles.getChildren().add(createCommandToggle("Command 1", "exec1"));
        commandToggles.getChildren().add(createCommandToggle("Command 2", "exec2"));
        commandToggles.getChildren().add(createCommandToggle("Command 3", "exec3"));
        // ...

        Button runButton = new Button("Run");
        runButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
            // ...
        });

        // ...

    }

    private ToggleButton createCommandToggle(String text, String executable) {
        ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton(text);
        button.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isSelected) -> {
            if (isSelected) { 
                commands.add(executable);
            } else {
                commands.remove(executable);
            }
        }
        return button ;
    }
}
```

As @Valette_Renoux suggests, you can refine this by encapsulating the text for the button and the executable command in an `enum`, and replace the list with an `EnumSet`. This makes building the toggle buttons a little less repetitive (though you might need just a little more work in the `runButton` handler to extract the commands).

Answer (score 0):

I would use an EnumSet. Define one enum constant for each Button (with a name property to display), then have the togglebutton add or remove the enum from the set. This way the button class only needs to have as arguments to the constructor which enum constant it is for, and the EnumSet.

It is then easy to add arguments to the command line by iterating over the EnumSet.

The advantage of this solution is that the Button class can be small and generic (adding one more command line option will be just adding a `new CommandOptionButton(Options.VERBOSE, optionsSet)`, and the set is much better algorithmically than adding and removing Strings from a list.